# How to format incomming Bluetooth stream?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, stream

I already have the stream being converted to string, but I would like to get it to just give me byte[].
This is my code

```
    public byte[] Read()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
            StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
            int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

            do
            {
                numberOfBytesRead = mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

                myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
            }
            while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable());

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myCompleteMessage, "Reading");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the complete message as a byte array instead of a string?

Comment: @Sylens Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect the data from all the intermediate buffers in a separate array. I am using an ArrayList to collect all the buffer data. After receiving the data, we will convert that ArrayList to an array.

```
public byte[] Read()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        var finalByteList = new ArrayList<byte>();

        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            finalByteList.AddRange(myReadBuffer)
            myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        }
        while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable());

        // here is the final array of bytes
        var finalByteArray = finalByteList.ToArray();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(myCompleteMessage, "Reading");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```